# GitLab AutoDevOps Error timeout deployment rollout to finish kubernetes

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-auto-devops

I applied the AutoDevOps gitlab-ci configuration. Connect Kubernetes cluster to DigitalOcean.
Pipeline timeout error. What could be the problem?

```
$ deploy
secret/myprod-xjxj5s-secret replaced
Deploying new release...
Release "myprod-xjxj5s" does not exist. Installing it now.
NAME:   myprod-xjxj5s
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Apr 11 21:59:35 2019
NAMESPACE: production
STATUS: DEPLOYED

NOTES:
Application should be accessible at: http://mydomain.ru/
Waiting for deployment "myprod-xjxj5s" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated replicas are available...
Pulling docker image gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-227934c0 ...
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```